# Jquery alter date format based on selector

Tags: jquery

My hands are tied a bit using FullCalendar.js to parse ical on my site.  I want to create a different format altogether but am limited a bit.  So my question is, can I use jQuery to re-format all the dates from a specific selector?

For example:

```
<tr class="fc-list-heading" data-date="2017-03-28">
<td class="fc-widget-header" colspan="3">
<span class="fc-list-heading-main">Tuesday</span>
<span class="fc-list-heading-alt">March 28, 2017</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Could I select all the .fc-list-heading-alt span classes and re-format the date to be like 28 March?  I've looked all over the net but havent found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for(var i = 0; i < $(".fc-list-heading-alt").length; i++)  {

    var elem =$(".fc-list-heading-alt").get(i);

    var date = new Date($(elem).text());
    
    $(elem).text(date.toDateString());

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="fc-list-heading" data-date="2017-03-28">
<td class="fc-widget-header" colspan="3">
<span class="fc-list-heading-main">Tuesday</span>
<span class="fc-list-heading-alt">March 28, 2017</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Check out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for all the functions of the Date object.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var date = new Date($('.fc-list-heading').attr("data-date"));
 var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
   ];
 $('.fc-list-heading-alt').text(date.getDate()+' '+monthNames[date.getMonth()]+', '+date.getFullYear());
});
```